# required does not force the field to have value

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am creating a form http://www.kjds.org/templates/articlecco_cdo/aid/2871032/jewish/Untitled.htm

If you look in the first section of this code there is Guests Tables and Unable to attend options, if you select the first 2 then the Attendees field enables and becomes required with javascript, but the problem is that i can still submit my form without filling out that field.

There is a difference for required and required="true" if the required="true" then field becomes indeed required. However i found that there is no difference if specifying required or not in the terms of demanded value.

I found that it i put required="true" i cannot manipulate it with JS, so I am limited to required.

I am using a private company's cms platform.

Please let me know if i am doing something wrong but as far as i see there is a problem with the platform that it lets required field go by unfilled.

Comment: Does this not work: `yourelement.setAttribute("required", "false");` ?

Comment: Ok... in HTML5 if you have the 'required' attribute, the form wont submit untill it has any kind of value.

Have you tried to use the a class instead of the attribute. A class called "required" and just add it or remove it depending on the user checks?

Comment: @NuclearPeon great that solved the problem

Comment: Excellent! Wrote it as an answer so it can be accepted. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
yourelement.setAttribute("required", "false");
```